# Modifying .py file in Eclipse and recreate .exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, eclipse

I have a Python project that I need to modify just one description in `main.py`
I tried to open the project in `Eclipse` and modified the label. but when I click on `GeneraXML.exe` it can not see the modification and show me the old label. this is the structure of my project.
[image]

Can anyone help me how can I modify it?

Comment: AFAIK PyDev is not able to execute .exe programs. You should be able to execute them from Eclipse if you install CDT (type "eclipse execute c++ exe" in your search engine). Alternatively you can just execute the .exe from your file browser.

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, If I am not wrong, I need to recreate the .spec file that read my main.py . But I have no idea how can I creare .spec file again?

Comment: Use [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) (something like`pyinstaller --onefile --distpath . --windowed main.py`)